# Geotools do not save prefs

Tags: geotools

I try to use org.geotools library on a server with readonly filesystem, but it tries to save preferences into userPreferences, which fails.
Is there a way of stopping geotools from trying?

Comment: see https://onexception.dev/news/1147452/geotools-preference-save-failure but apparently you can  save them somewhere else